# why angular js routing does not work?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a menu in `_Adminlayout.cshtml` and i define my `Route` in it , this is all i did in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Styles/ThirdParties/Glazzed/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <link href="~/Content/Styles/GlazzedOverride.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Scripts/ThirdParties/Glazzed/Main.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Scripts/ThirdParties/Angular.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/Scripts/ThirdParties/AngularRoute.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 @DefineApp()
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col col-md-9 pull-left">
            @RenderBody()
            @*<ng-view></ng-view>*@
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-2 bg1">
            <ul class="main-nav" ng-controller="menuController">
                <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" class="{{ menuItem.submenuItems && menuItem.submenuItems.length > 0 ? 'main-nav--collapsible' : '' }}">
                    <a class="main-nav__link" ng-href="{{ menuItem.url || 'javascript:void(0);' }}">
                        <span class="main-nav__icon"><i class="{{ menuItem.icon }}"></i></span>
                        {{ menuItem.title }}
                    </a>
                    <ul ng-if="menuItem.submenuItems && menuItem.submenuItems.length > 0" class="main-nav__submenu">
                        <li ng-repeat="submenuItem in menuItem.submenuItems"><a href="{{ submenuItem.url || 'javascript:void(0);' }}"><span>{{ submenuItem.title }}</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the script :

```
    <script>
        App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            debugger;
            $routeProvider
                .when('/Admin/GetProducts', {
                    templateUrl: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Product")'
                })                  
                .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }]);
        App.controller("menuController", function ($scope) {
            debugger;
            $scope.menuItems = [
                {
                    title: 'ProductList',
                    icon: 'pe-7f-check',
                    url: '#/Admin/GetProducts'
                }
            ]});
    </script>
</div>
```

```
 @helper  DefineApp()
         {
         <script>
             var App = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
        </script>
      }
```

but my route does not work, what is the problem?

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: no, i really confuse

Comment: Are you sure it's finding this templateUrl: 'templateUrl: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Product")''

Comment: I think you have not redirected to any route, try `.otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/Admin/GetProducts'
            });`

Comment: i added it but it the url become : http://localhost:3473/Admin/Product/GetProducts#/Admin/GetProducts

Comment: When i run project to see another view  for example :/Admin/Home/Index the url(on browser) become :http://localhost:3473/Admin/Home/Index#/  , and then i click on menu the url became :
http://localhost:3473/Admin/Home/Index#/Admin/GetProducts

Comment: What happens if you change url to : '/#/Admin/GetProducts ?

Comment: the browser will crash!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing Angular routing which was designed for SPA's and you also have MVC routing which isn't for SPA's. You have both technologies essentially fighting each other.

If you want to use Angular routing or Angular is general, I would recommend that you stop having your ASP.NET MVC controllers from returning any Views except for maybe "Index.cshtml"